# How do I copy files recursively through a directory tree while appending parent folder names to the new files? Batch or VBScript

Tags: recursion, vbscript, cmd, batch-rename, directory-structure

What I'm trying to do is copy a couple hundred images scattered throughout a directory tree and copy them all to another, single folder. I've found out how to do that with 'for /r %i in (*.jpg) ', but my main issue is that the files are all named using the same conventions. Sample:

```
    Parent_Folder
        001
            file1.jpg
            file2.jpg
        002
            file1.jpg
            file2.jpg
```

The list continues as such. What I'm aiming to do is create this:

```
    Dest_Folder
        001_file1.jpg
        001_file2.jpg
        002_file1.jpg
        002_file2.jpg
```

where the file's parent directory's name is added to the front of the files (so as to keep them listed in the same order). Not even individually going through every folder and using the "copy & rename" option will work since that will list all files named "file1.jpg" one after the other, "file2.jpg", and so on.

If there's any way to do this in a batch file, that would be much preferred, but a VBScript wouldn't be a bad choice either.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT

Magoo has given the perfect answer for my issue, but it seems his script only works if the source & destination paths have no spaces in them, despite the double quotes. I tried using this same script on another image collection, but with spaces in the paths, and I'm given an error saying the '[word after the first space in the path] was not expected at this time'. It was simple enough to just rename the folders, perform the copy, the rename them back, but is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.jpg) DO (
 SET "newname=%%a"
 SET "newname=!newname:*%sourcedir%\=!"
 ECHO COPY /b "%%a" "%destdir%\!newname:\=_!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Grab each filename, remove the source directory name and a `\`, then copy the file to that name, changing each `\` to `_`.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

---

Edit : fixed to allow spaces in `sourcedir` (simply quote after the `/r` in the `for`)

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I need it to! The only edits I made were substituting my own paths (of course) and an extra SET command to make all the spaces in the file names into underscores (consistency OCD on my part). Perfect!

Comment: I tried using this same script on another image collection, but with spaces in the paths, and I'm given an error saying the '[word after the first space is the path] was not expected at this time'. It was simple enough to just rename the folders, but do you have any thoughts for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub BuildFileName(ParentFolder)

    Dim objFSO, objFolder, strFileName 
    Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ParentFolder)

    For Each folder In objFolder.SubFolders
        For Each file In folder.Files
            strFileName = ParentFolder & "_" & folder.Name & "_" & file.Name
            WScript.Echo strFileName
        Next 
    Next 
End Sub 

Call BuildFileName("c:\scripts")
```